# How can I restrict analytics embed api to display only one google analytics account

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How can I restrict analytics embed api to display only one google analytics account. Right now I have three accounts showing up under dropdown.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Philip Walton said, the viewselector will always show all accounts etc. And to have only one 'view' you will not need the selector and add the id to the chart data

As example, in case you would use the https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide demo as a starting point. To have it show only one view, replace step 3 to 6 by:

```
<script>
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  // Step 3: Authorize the user.

  var CLIENT_ID = 'insert client id here';

  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'auth-button',
    clientid: CLIENT_ID,
  });



  // Step 4: Create the timeline chart.

  var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    reportType: 'ga',
    query: {
      'ids': 'ga:insert view id here',
      'dimensions': 'ga:date',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'LINE',
      container: 'timeline'
    }
  });

    timeline.execute();


});
</script>
```

So you can delete step 4 and 6 of the original one and edit step 5 by adding ids: YOURVIEWID to var timeline. Afterwards add timeline.execute() to render the chart

The ids needed can be found by using https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/account-explorer/ and the needed id is displayed at the button under 'view'

Answer (score 3):

The Embed API's `ViewSelector` component is always going to show you a list of all your accounts, properties, and views.

If you know exactly what view you want to display data for, then you don't need to use the `ViewSelector` component at all, you just need to pass the view ID (`ids`) directly to the `Report` or `DataChart` components.

Comment: Thanks, not sure if I understand what you mean because I'm just learning  in embed api. What do you mean by "view you want display data for"? Also what is a view ID and where I can find it?
For instance I would like to get a visual graph of all sessions but just for one account, how can I do that? Any code snippet would help. Thanks

Comment: A search for "Google Analytics view" returns: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2649553

Comment: You can use the [Account Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/account-explorer/) to find your view IDs and `ids` values.

Comment: Thank you very much this was very helpful!

Comment: @PhilipWalton can we hide selectors ? on page load just show the analytics, selectors should not display ?